# How to keep good boot speed using multple OS on 1 PC?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

It would be really handy if i could switch to linux from time to time as my second OS installed. But when I switched to GRUB last time it affected windows's ability to hibernate, super fast boot was gone. Instead every time I opened my laptop i had to wait for the whole boot, then had to choose OS from boot menu - much, much longer. **Is it any way i could keep same instant boot loads and have an ability to switch to different OS only when i need to? Like restart the system, push a button during restart and have the boot menu?** Something like that.

PS I have only one SSD on my laptop.

Comment: Did you try to use a VM (VirtualBox or else) for the OS you only use occasionally?

Comment: Yeah, i wanted specifically point out in the question that i don't wanna use VM. It's just a laptop with limited hardware resources. And also when i would switch to Linux  im gonna work there for some time, so i want full experience. Otherwise i just would use Putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really asking about "boot speed".  You're asking about resuming from hibernation, or fast-boot.  (fast-boot is essentially a more-advanced version of hibernation)

The short answer:  No.

The longer-answer:  Standard "hibernation" works by copying RAM and the CPU state to the disk, and powering off.  When resuming, the process is reversed.  Stuff in NVRAM doesn't need to be powered in order to "hibernate", so that is left untouched.  The advantage of doing this is that it doesn't require all the hardware to be re-initialized.  It just resumes doing what it was doing before it was hibernated.  Loading another OS, will certainly modify the contents of NVRAM and modify the state of various devices, causing the saved state to no longer be 100% safe to resume from.  The way drivers initialize hardware in Linux is almost always different from the way the drivers initialize hardware in Windows.

It would be really horrible for the disk-controller driver to resume blindly with nvram contents that would start overwriting sectors that it shouldn't...  or have a USB-C port supply 20v to a device expecting 5v... or who knows what else.

More and more hardware are starting to implement more "in-between" states, where the computer is sort-of asleep... and sort-of awake.  A classic example of this is "WoL" or Wake on LAN... where the network port isn't powered off, it just listens on the network for a specific kind of packet and causes the whole PC to resume.  These technologies are getting more and more advanced, where (for-example) a server could be in a semi-asleep mode, until a http request comes in, and resume fast-enough to accept the TCP connection... instead of a simple "WoL" magic packet to wake the server up.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but thank you for an amazing answer!